# Convert WGS-84 position into lat/lng

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, wgs84

I am using leafletjs. I have a list of "WGS-84" positions that look like:

LATITUDE 
`N45 52.1096`
LONGITUDE 
`W125 52.4665`

LATITUDE 
`N48 24.1051`
LONGITUDE 
`E174 37.3832`

What is the significance of the alpha-numeric start to these positions? Can they be ignored and can I just use the normal lat/lng floats that follow them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The N or S value of Latitude is whether the location is North or South of the Equator. W or E for Longitude, is W or E of the Prime Meridian. The number that follows the letter is the Degree of Latitude or Longitude, followed by minutes and seconds of Latitude/Longitude displayed as floats. The alpha-numeric values should not be ignored as they are part of the location.

Comment: Leaflet expects 2 numbers for lat/lng not alphanumeric, is there a way to convert these? http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng

Comment: Link to a website for Converting Coordinates: http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx Im sure some projection algorithm exists

Comment: It's also possible that those are *decimal minutes* not "minutes and seconds".  The provider should specify the format somewhere. "Projection" is not necessary, just reformatting to decimal degrees.

Comment: Could you elaborate on reformatting to decimal degrees?

Comment: This link provides the math that goes along with reformatting to decimal degrees: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/degrees-minutes-seconds-to-degrees.htm

Comment: Which part is degrees, minutes, and seconds from "N45 52.1096"? And if 45 is degrees, would "E174" still be 174 degrees (i.e what role does the cardinal direction play)

Comment: explained in my answer.

Comment: OK so in the converter you last linked to, I can ignore N/W/E/S and just input the number following it for degrees.

Comment: So "N45 52.1096" becomes Degrees: 45, Minutes: 52, Seconds: 1096

Comment: What you have appears to be Degrees and Minutes.         Degrees Minutes 45°52.10960', -125°52.46650'

Comment: I see, so put 0 for seconds, and the result is + for N/E and - for S/W